# the concept of Every-case Time complexity

Tags: algorithm, performance

[image: every-case time complexity example]

This is a slide from my lecture notes. I understand that if an algorithm's best-case and worst-case complexity are the same then it has "every-case" complexity.  However I do not fully understand this concept.  I tried researching online but it didn't help.

Can somebody with other examples explain what every-case time complexity more generally?

Comment: I've never seen the idea, it looks like the invention of an over-eager undergraduate text author.

Comment: what is best-case complexity???

Comment: @A.S.H https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best,_worst_and_average_case#Best-case_performance_for_algorithm

Comment: wow, i agree with the last sentence ;). but formally, what is stated is true, as in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found out that the lower bound - the asymptotic minimum number of operations to add array members is O(n).

You found out that the upper bound - the asymptotic maximum number of operations to add array members is O(n).

So, all the other cases are between O(n) and O(n). So they must be O(n) too.

Comment: But whatever i have said about  "every-case" complexity. is It true
?

Answer (score 1):

The concept is from Napolitaner book Foundation of algorithms (chapter 1) and is related to algorithms that every time do the same steps regardless of input size (eg. add a number to every elements of an array). Pay attention that not every algorithms can be analized with every case analisys. HTH